# AttributeError: 'ResourceVariable' object has no attribute '_distribute_strategy'

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I try to implement ELMo word embedding in a Bi-LSTM model. But when I finish my code in Google Colab with tensorflow, I meet some problems.

There is an "AttributeError". I think the architecture of my model is correct, but I don't know where the problem is.

```
INFO:tensorflow:Saver not created because there are no variables in the graph to restore
INFO:tensorflow:Saver not created because there are no variables in the graph to restore
Model: "model_5"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_6 (InputLayer)            [(200, 200)]         0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
elmo_embedding_5 (ElmoEmbedding (200, 200, 1024)     4           input_6[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_11 (Dense)                (200, 200, 1024)     1049600     elmo_embedding_5[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_3 (Bidirectional) (200, 200, 256)      2623488     dense_11[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_Tanh_6 (TensorFlowO [(200, 200, 256)]    0           bidirectional_3[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_12 (Dense)                (200, 200, 1)        257         tf_op_layer_Tanh_6[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_MatMul_3 (TensorFlo [(200, 1, 256)]      0           dense_12[0][0]                   
                                                                 bidirectional_3[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_Tanh_7 (TensorFlowO [(200, 1, 256)]      0           tf_op_layer_MatMul_3[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
flatten_5 (Flatten)             (200, 256)           0           tf_op_layer_Tanh_7[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_13 (Dense)                (200, 1)             257         flatten_5[0][0]                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 3,673,606
Trainable params: 3,673,606
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-ec34ae4d734a> in <module>()
     56 
     57 model = ElmoClassification()
---> 58 model.run(data.train_reviews, data.train_labels, batch_size=200, epochs=100)

12 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py in variable_created_in_scope(self, v)
   3566 
   3567   def variable_created_in_scope(self, v):
-> 3568     return v._distribute_strategy is None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   3569 
   3570   def _experimental_distribute_dataset(self, dataset, options):

AttributeError: 'ResourceVariable' object has no attribute '_distribute_strategy'
```

Comment: Can you please provide the complete code  ?If you were trying to train your model , the operation will be model.fit() . Instructions can be found here for model.fit() and other model operations.    https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#methods_2

Comment: can somebody answer this as i am facing same issue while training bert embedding using lstm model.